# Error Column Formula

Tags: calculated-column

I would like to create a calculated column to return a text value based on a score in another column but I cant get the syntax correct. can someone help?

```
Low = 0 - 35
Med = 36 - 70
High = 71- 105
V high = 106 +
```

Comment: Write your Formula in Excel first, SharePoint is 1:1 for this simple formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(Col>=0,Col<=35),"Low",
IF(AND(Col>=36,Col<=70),"Med",
IF(AND(Col>=71,Col<=105),"High",
IF(AND(Col>10),"V High",""))))
```

Consider Col is your column name from which you want value to be evaluated .Try this Formula

Added extra condition, if value is less than 0 this column will return blank value

Comment: Thank you for your help, definitely worth putting into excel first.

Answer (score 1):

Overly complex to use AND

```
=IF( Col<36 
     ,"Low"
     ,IF( Col<71 
          ,"Med",
          IF( Col<106 
              ,"High",
              ,"Very High"
            )
        )
    )
```